# Hi i want to copy text in redfonts to new tab

Tags: fonts, tabs, copy

Hi i have data in TAB1 which has red and black fonts, I want to have a new tab with only the red ones. the TAB1 is regularly updated and red and black fonts are regularly changing. I want to automize copying of red fonts.

I am expecting a formula or command that will automatically copy and populate my new tab with red fonts only.